# Unexpectedly long query time NDBCluster

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster

I'm having an issue where some queries take an abnormal execution time, meaning 3 to 5 seconds.

This part of the schema is 2 tables A and B, where A has many to one relation to table B.

Table A:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKF9A4C12670427173` (`bId`),
  KEY `FKF9A4C126F3F3A79E` (`refId`)
) ENGINE=ndbcluster DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table B:

```
CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `refNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `altId` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `foo` (`foo`),
  KEY `altId_index` (`altId`),
) ENGINE=ndbcluster DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I make any query which contains a restriction on the A.refId the query is extremely slow, in 3 to 5 second range.

```
select * from A a where a.bId in (select id from B b where b.altId like 'foobar') and a.refId = 'reference';
```

Table B has only one row where the altId matches, and there are about 500k rows in table A where refId is 'reference'.
I know that the large row count is probably reason for the long execution time, but I don't see why, or how to fix it.

The MySQL explain for the execution plan shows the following:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'a', 'ref', 'FKF9A4C12670427173,FKF9A4C126F3F3A79E', 'FKF9A4C126F3F3A79E', '258', 'const', '9', 'Parent of 2 pushed join@1; Using where with pushed condition'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'b', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,altId_index', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'a.bId', '1', 'Child of \'a\' in pushed join@1; Using where with pushed condition'
```

So if anyone can shed a bit of light what is causing this, or how to fix it, that would be much appreciated.